# content in ng-repeat (as a for-loop) does not update

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to AngularJS. Please help me with this problem.

This page would fetch a list from server and display the items.
I want it to be 6 items in a row. (Bootstrap is used, so a row is class="row")
The "range" filter makes ng-repeat works like a for-loop.

```
<div ng-repeat="row in [] | range: Math.ceil(data.length / 6)" class="row">
     <div ng-repeat="col in [] | range: 6" ng-if="data[row * 6 + col]" ng-init="upload=data[row * 6 + col]" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
          <div class="thumbnail">
               <img ng-src="../show.php?action=file.show&id={{upload.id}}" />                           
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The first render works fine. However, after an ajax call to delete an item from server, this list does not update. I suspect it is due to the Math.ceil does not change always.

May anyone please kindly suggest a solution?
Thank you very much!

Comment: If you suspect the Math.ceil() could be the problem, try and remove it, using a fixed value, and see if that fixes the problem. If it doesn't, then you know that its something else. It it does, you know what to fix.

Comment: Try use $scope.$apply() after deleting item from table. Remember that bindings will no update when retrieving, or changing data asynchronously.

Comment: Maciej Wojsław, yes I have tried apply(), but I see this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog So I suspect Angular does update the page content for me, but not good enough. i.e. Math.ceil(data.length / 6) is still the same value, hence update is stopped?